# policy routing for local outcoming connections

Tags: linux, iptables, iproute2, policy-routing

I have a multihomed setup with two upstream providers. And I want to confine some connections to use only one provider — local outgoing connections that is. So, I've made a custom routing table, which has a directly-connected network route and a default route:

```
$ ip route show table 2
default via 5.1.0.1 dev upstream_b
5.1.0.0/16 dev upstream_b  scope link  src 5.1.0.2
```

Next, I'm using a selector in iptables to add fwmark to some connections and ip-rule to override routing table selection:

```
# for output traffic
# restore packet mark from connection mark
iptables --table mangle --append OUTPUT -j CONNMARK --restore-mark
# for !0 packet marks bail out
iptables --table mangle --append OUTPUT -m mark ! --mark 0 -j ACCEPT
# set packet mark
iptables --table mangle --append OUTPUT -m cgroup --cgroup 0x00010002 -j MARK --set-mark 0x2
# save packet mark to connection mark
iptables --table mangle --append OUTPUT -j CONNMARK --save-mark
# for input traffic restoring mark from connmark
iptables --table mangle --append PREROUTING -j CONNMARK --restore-mark
# adding policy forwarding
ip rule add from all fwmark 2 table 2
```

So, for some process [in the specified `net_cls` cgroup] its outgoing connections will hit connection mark rule and then should be routed via `upstream_b` interface.

But that is not working (for a bash shell, which was put into the net_cls cgroup):

```
$ curl --resolve ifconfig.co:80:188.113.88.193 -v http://ifconfig.co
* Added ifconfig.co:80:188.113.88.193 to DNS cache
* Rebuilt URL to: http://ifconfig.co/
* Hostname ifconfig.co was found in DNS cache
*   Trying 188.113.88.193...
* Immediate connect fail for 188.113.88.193: Network is unreachable
* Closing connection 0
curl: (7) Couldn't connect to server
```

The previous result took place while `main` routing table has no default route (i.e. no route to ifconfig.co).

But this is not the whole story. Since I have the multihomed setup, there usually is a ECMP route to balance traffic via both providers. And for the mentioned test I got an interesting result. The tcp-syn packages went to the correct interface but with an incorrect source address (from the other interface).

So, joining these observations, firstly, a routing decision is made based on `main` routing table (thus, network is unreachable). Next, while a package is processed further, it hits the marking rules and then a rerouting happens (based on the custom routing table). But the source address is already set in the first routing decision, and it is not corrected here.

**Is my understanding of the problem origins correct?**

I need to enforce a non-default routing table for some local processes and the method above is not working. **Could the enforcement be accomplished?** For example, is it possible to trigger the source address recalculation?

EDIT. Considering the following diagram (the kernel version here is not that modern, but still useful; the diagram is from http://open-source.arkoon.net/kernel/kernel_net.png): [image: kernel path]

It seems that the first routing decision and the package source address selection are indeed performed before any iptables rule could kick in (see right bottom corner).